# how to add html header tags(h1-h6) inside textbox in ssrs 2008?

Tags: html, header, ssrs-2008

How to add html header tags(h1-h6) inside textbox in  ssrs 2008. I am new to ssrs, I want use header tags for headings in reports

like using in html heading tags(h1-h6). I searched allot, but all are saying placeholder concept which I dont know. Also I want display only '**text heading**', not with Dataset value.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,

Suresh

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty easy. Inside textbox right click and select "Create placeholder..", next you have to select HTML as Markup type. You can write any html code into value field.

Comment: It is getting updated the styles with html tags. However when I trying to check code with "Inspect Element" by right on browser, it was showing under SPAN tag(<span></span>). Can you please help me on this, why this happened and how to resolve. Please don't mind if I am asking easy query. I am very new to ssrs. Thank you. I am using the code inside value: ="<h2>Heading1</h2>"

Comment: You're right, each html placeholder creates <span></span> elements. I'm not sure if it can be removed. Also see the blog post:  [link](http://dinesql.blogspot.com/2010/05/reporting-services-2008-showing-html.html)